# How to select elements in the intersection of two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

As a quick example:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a', 'stack', 'overflow']
for i in list1 and list2:
    print i
```

this prints all the elements in `list2`. Why is this? How can I just print the elements that are in both lists?

Comment: ```for i in list 1: if i in list2: print i```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your lists can be big, its better to convert them to sets and use intersection over them:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a', 'stack', 'overflow']

for i in set(list1).intersection(set(list2)):
    print i
```

In case you want to iterate on that intersection repetitively, save it in a variable of its own (`intersect = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))`).

You could also use:

```
for i in list 1:
    if i in list2:
        print i
```

but the problem of using `in` in a list for checking membership is that it can be an `O(n)` operation, so overall, your loop becomes O(n^2). OTOH, using `in` on a `set` for membership is O(1), so it is much faster.

As for your original question, when you do `for i in list1 and list2`, it is interpreted as `for i in (list1 and list2)`, and the value of `list1 and list2` is simply list2 if list1 is not empty, so you end up iterating over the second list only.

Comment: @ mu無 does that create any side effects?

Comment: @AlanH I've added some more explanation, have a look at that. If the answer helps, don't forget to accept and upvote :)